# Insertion of data into db not working for Laravel 5.4 on server(working on localhost)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I am trying to deploy a project involving basic CRUD operations using Laravel 5.4 on cpanel server. 
I am trying to insert an Item into my Database. My updation and deletion code seems to be working but insertion isn't.

Please note that on Localhost everything is working but on the server Insertion isn't.

Here's the Code and different php files. 
My controller is gendersController which has all the CRUD functions.

**Web.php(gender route)**

```
Route::resource('/genders','gendersController');
```

**Create.php (View on which we are seeing a form with a single field and submit button)**

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('body')
<br>
<a href="/genders" class="btn btn-info" >Back</a>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
<h1>{{substr(Route::currentRouteName(),8)}} item</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/genders/@yield('editid')" 
method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
@section('editMethod')
@show
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-10">
   <label>Gender Type <input type="text" class="form-control"  
name="gendertypes" id="gendertypes" value="@yield('editgendertypes')">
 </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
   @include('partial.errors')
   </div>
   @endsection
```

**gendersController.php (genders Controller)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\gender;
use DB;

class gendersController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{

     $genders= gender::paginate(1000);
    return view('gender.index',compact('genders'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
   return view('gender.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $gender = new gender;
    $this->validate($request,[
           'gendertypes'=>'required',
        ]);
   $gender->gendertypes=$request->gendertypes;

   $gender->save();
   session()->flash('message','Added Successfully');
   return redirect('/genders');

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
     return $id;
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
   $gender = gender::find($id);
    return view('gender.edit',compact('gender'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $gender = gender::find($id);
    $gender->gendertypes=$request->gendertypes;
   $gender->save();
   session()->flash('message','Updated Successfully');
   return redirect('/genders');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $gender=gender::find($id);
   $gender->delete();
   session()->flash('message','Delete Successfully');
   return redirect('/genders');
}
}
```

**Here are the images**

**Main View(this is were all the data from the database gets displayed. Also has the add button**

url: domainname/genders

![Genders view]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmQVV.jpg

**Add new Gender view**

url: domainname/genders/create

![Create View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sup7V.jpg

After adding for some reason, I get redirected to the main view page without any insertion being made into the database (because of this the new data is not displayed on the main view page)

Can't find the error!!

Comment: You set gendertypes as required but you are not showing any error message in your view if you submit empty. Please add {!! $errors->first('gendertypes') !!} in your view & check if it shows error message. This could be one of the reason it redirects you to back without any message

Comment: Are you deploying the site on a subdirectory? e.g. example.com/subdir/[laravel_here]

Comment: @manian thanks for your reply. I have already done that on validations are working fine. The file in which the errors have been defined is 'partial.errors' which I have included in the view already. It is working fine.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for replying.The folder directory on the Cpanel server is as follows:

    public_html
    /some folder name/contains all the files like app, config 
    etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the url your form is posting to. Because you hardcode the urls in the forms `/genders/x` instead of using named routes with generated urls relative to your installations doc root, the form will post to

`http://your.domain.com/genders/`

instead of

`http://your.domain.com/some_folder_name/genders`

That's why on localhost everything works fine, but once you deploy it in a subdirectory it will not.

You are using a resource route, so `route('genders.store')` should work just fine in your view. Check available routes and their names through `php artisan route:list`.

---

Sidenote: Try and avoid placing the files outside of Laravel's public path  in a public_html directory (or a publicly subdir for that matter). There's a reason why some directories and files are outside of the document root.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your answer. What you've suggested is correct. I've tried it and it's working now. :)